# tensorflow dataset from generator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using such code to recursively load images from directory and get associated labels - directory names. But when I have more images, it crashes due memory error. I would like to use generator, but I am really stuck with it. Could somebody help? The code without generator is:

```
import pathlib
import random

data_dir = "./images"

print(data_dir)
data_root = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
all_image_paths = list(data_root.glob('*/*'))
all_image_paths = [str(path) for path in all_image_paths]

label_names = sorted(item.name for item in data_root.glob('*/') if item.is_dir())
label_to_index = dict((name, index) for index,name in enumerate(label_names))

all_image_labels = [label_to_index[pathlib.Path(path).parent.name] for path in all_image_paths]

path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_image_paths)
image_ds = path_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=8)
label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.cast(all_image_labels, tf.int64))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((image_ds, label_ds))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(params.train_size)buffer
dataset = dataset.repeat(params.num_epochs)
dataset = dataset.batch(params.batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1) to serve

return dataset
```

Comment: There is probably nothing wrong with your code.. you may have too big shuffle buffer. Why would you want to use generator if you have everything in tensorflow operations and nothing in python?

Comment: I am not so experienced with Tensorflow, I am more in Keras. I am trying to use Facenet implementation https://github.com/omoindrot/tensorflow-triplet-loss/issues to learn embedings of (224,224,3) pictures. When I use 2000 pictures, it is ok. But I need 25k and later 250k pictures. And even when I have someting like 5k pictures, the code freezes. I will try to remove the shuffle, maybee it will help

Comment: Maybe just try to add one line of code at a time and see what line causes the freezing. There may also be some side effects of load_and_preprocess_images if you are using python function in there, etc.

Comment: Ok so I removed the shuffle line and I am able to process 500k images. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`. Creating dataset from images with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` writes data chunks in the graph as tf.constant(), wasting memory. With a large enough dataset you can hit Tensorflow's 2GB GraphDef limit.
You just need to define dataset using placeholders

```
features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(features.dtype, features.shape)
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(labels.dtype, labels.shape)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
```

As explained here
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays

Comment: I will try it. Thank you

Comment: This is irrelevant. He's using from dataset slices for only image paths that should not reach over 2gb in total.

Comment: This is common practice from official docs. Buffer size may affect data parsing, but 250K images is way too small quantity to cause any problems, considering images are something like (224,224,3) in size

Comment: @TomasBatrla, just keep us updated on how it's gonna work out

Comment: Large datasets should be processed on the fly.. the stuff you are citing from the docs is for something between small dataset and large enough RAM. But it even doesn't matter since this example does not load dataset into RAM. It load only filenames that are a few megabytes at most.

Comment: looks like removing shuffle was a good step. It works now with 25k images

Comment: @user2781994 but I am loading images into memory. See the line 


image_ds = path_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=8)

Comment: Sure, but it is done while training and only one batch is loaded in RAM at any given time (or a constant number of batches). After train op it is discarded and new batch is loaded from disk. (Very roughly speaking - all of this is done concurrently)

Comment: Ok, this is better than I though. I will keep you updated

Comment: Ok so I removed the shuffle line and I am able to process 500k images. Thanks!

Comment: You can add the shuffle line back, but keep in mind that the whole shuffle buffer needs to be stored in RAM. Therefore lower the size of shuffle buffer to a point where input data are reasonably shuffled but you don't exceed available RAM.